# Why build strings with helper functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Saw this on https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript

Can someone please explain how this is more efficient, i.e., why this avoids temporary string results?

> Build up long strings by passing string builders (either an array or a
>   helper class) into functions, to avoid temporary result strings.
>
> For example, assuming `buildMenuItemHtml_` needs to build up a string
>   from literals and variables and would use a string builder internally,
>   instead of using:
>
> ```
> var strBuilder = [];
> for (var i = 0, length = menuItems.length; i < length; i++) {
>   strBuilder.push(this.buildMenuItemHtml_(menuItems[i]));
> }
> var menuHtml = strBuilder.join();
> ```
>
> Use:
>
> ```
> var strBuilder = [];
> for (var i = 0, length = menuItems.length; i < length; i++) {
>   this.buildMenuItem_(menuItems[i], strBuilder);
> }
> var menuHtml = strBuilder.join();
> ```

I assumed in the first case `buildMenuItemHtml_` returned a `string` and in the second case `buildMenuItemHtml_` pushed a `string` onto `strBuilder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important detail is where it says that `buildMenuItemHtml_` builds a string from a bunch of different elements. Between the two examples, this happens in two different ways:

Example 1 (builds a string directly):

```
function buildMenuItemHtml_(data) {
  return ["<li>",data.x,"</li>"].join();
}
```

or Example 2 (uses a supplied string builder):

```
function buildMenuItemHtml_(data, strBuilder) {
  strBuilder.push("<li>");
  strBuilder.push(data.x);
  strBuilder.push("</li>");
}
```

String building is relatively expensive and wasteful since it requires lots of allocations and copies, some of which are temporary and likely to get thrown out. Pushing onto an array is comparatively cheap, and `join()`ing even a large array ONCE is better than `join()`ing a whole bunch of small arrays many times.

So rather than having each iteration of the loop build a temporary string (expensive), only to go and build another string (expensive) with those strings, the guideline suggests passing your main string builder directly into the `buildMenuItemHtml_` function. By doing this, you don't do any expensive string building until your whole collection of elements is ready -- i.e. once.

Answer (score 1):

By pushing the entire function `this.buildMenutItemHtml_` into `strBuilder` you are essentially allocating memory each iteration for the entire `this.buildMenuItemHtml` function and all of it's internal variables which would create temporary string variables before it returns your string value to `strBuilder`. The second method will return the string from the original `this.buildMenutItemHtml` in memory and push that into `strBuilder` making it more efficient since it is not allocating new memory each iteration to handle the `this.buildMenuItemHtml` function.

Answer (score 0):

> I assumed in the first case buildMenuItemHtml_ returned a string

Yes.

> and in the second case buildMenuItemHtml_ pushed a string onto strBuilder.

No. The relevant piece of information is "*assuming `buildMenuItemHtml_` needs to build up a string from literal**s and** variable**s** and would use a string builder internally*".

Instead of using an internal string builder, evaluating it and pushing the [temporary, intermediate] result string to the passed string builder, it now would simply push all of the items to the passed string builder directly.

It does not make a difference if `buildMenuItemHtml_` would just return a single literal or so and not do any string concatenation on its own.

---

Without actual example code for `buildMenuItemHtml_`, this is of course hard to understand. Maybe this helps:

### Bad:

```
function buildMenuHtml(menuItems) {
    var strBuilder = ["<ul>"];
    for (var i = 0, length = menuItems.length; i < length; i++) {
        strBuilder.push(buildMenuItemHtml(menuItems[i]));
    }
    strBuilder.push("</ul>");
    var menuHtml = strBuilder.join();
    return menuHtml;
}
function buildMenuItemHtml(item) {
    var innerStrBuilder = ["<li>"];
    for (prop in item)
        innerStrBuilder.push(prop, ": ", item[prop]);
    innerStrBuilder.push("</li>");
    var itemHtml = innerStrBuilder.join();
    return itemHtml;
}
```

### Good:

```
function buildMenuHtml(menuItems) {
    var strBuilder = ["<ul>"];
    for (var i = 0, length = menuItems.length; i < length; i++) {
        buildMenuItemHtml(menuItems[i], strBuilder);
    }
    strBuilder.push("</ul>");
    var menuHtml = strBuilder.join();
    return menuHtml;
}
function buildMenuItemHtml(item, strBuilder) {
    strBuilder.push("<li>");
    for (prop in item)
        strBuilder.push(prop, ": ", item[prop]);
    strBuilder.push("</li>");
    // no intermediate itemHtml!
}
```